# Requested PaperSize is not available on the currently selected printer

Tags: vba, excel, page-setup

I would like to copy some excel data in to a word document using VBA

The excel data is build for print area A3. After creating a word document, I am trying to set up paper size for new word document to A3. It is giving me a run time error

Run time error '5889'
Requested PaperSize is not available on the currently selected printer

VBA Code that I am using

```
Set obj = CreateObject("Word.Application")
obj.Visible = True
Set newobj = obj.Documents.Add
newobj.ActiveWindow.Selection.PageSetup.PaperSize = wdPaperA3

Sheets("Page1").Activate
Range("A1:Q18").Copy

newobj.ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteExcelTable False, False, True
newobj.ActiveWindow.Selection.InsertBreak Type:=7
```

Tried a different approach that is also giving me the same error

```
On Error Resume Next
Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

If wdApp Is Nothing Then
Set wdApp = GetObject("", "Word.Application")
End If

With wdApp
.Documents.Add
.Visible = True
End With
With wdApp.Selection
.PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientPortrait
.PageSetup.PaperSize = wdPaperA3
.PageSetup.MirrorMargins = wdNarrow
.PasteSpecial , Link:=False, DataType:=14, _
    DisplayAsIcon:=False
End With
Set wdApp = Nothing
```

Comment: Why selection? A hint for you. Record the macro and do what you want. You'll see how the job can be done. Later you can clear the code.

Comment: Does the default printer on your system support A3 paper size?

Comment: Thanks Gentlemen. I have decided to resize the excel to fit A4 :)